# RestKit - Data not persisting between app launches

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

In my RestKit application, I need to store an email and password in CoreData (I know about NSUserDefaults, but I have other user properties I need stored in CoreData as well).

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
NSError *error = nil;
NSEntityDescription *userEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:userEntity];
NSArray *users = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
return (User *)[users firstObject];
```

This user object is always null at the application launch.

Then, when the user enters his/her information, I save it like so:

```
- (void)cacheEmailAndPassword:(NSDictionary *)credentials {

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

NSError *error = nil;
NSEntityDescription *userEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:userEntity];
NSArray *users = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; //should be a single object array for now
User *user = (User *)[users firstObject];

user.email = [credentials objectForKey:@"email"];
user.password = [credentials objectForKey:@"password"];
}
```

Afterwards, when I try to get the User data from the first function, it returns with all the information.  However, when I relaunch the program, the data is null again.  Why is this data not persisting between application launches?

EDIT:  In case I screwed something up in my initialization, I've pasted it below:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Model" ofType:@"momd"]];
// NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

// Initialize the Core Data stack
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

// Configure the object manager
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

NSPersistentStore __unused *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Set the default store shared instance
[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];



[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
```

Comment: where is your [context save] command? If you don't run the command and are using a singleton as your context, you'll have access to the info until the app is stopped and your instance variable removed from memory. Then the next time the app loads, it won't have anything because you never explicitly saved it to the database

Comment: I just added `[context save:&anErrorVar]` to the `cacheEmailAndPassword` method, and nothing changed.

Comment: Hmm, RestKit looks like it's  little different. Try this command instead  `if(![context saveToPersistentStore:&executeError]) {
          NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store");
     }`. For more information, check out this SO question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593709/ios-restkit-can-not-save-local-entity-to-database

Comment: what kind of storage are you using? Persistent or in memory?

Comment: Yeah that didn't work either.  For clarification I added my initialization methods to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to add persistent storage

```
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"storage" ofType:@"momd"]];
// NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

BOOL success = RKEnsureDirectoryExistsAtPath(RKApplicationDataDirectory(), &error);
if (! success) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed to create Application Data Directory at path '%@': %@", RKApplicationDataDirectory(), error);
}
NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyStore.sqlite"];
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
if (! persistentStore) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed adding persistent store at path '%@': %@", path, error);
}
```

And whenever you are done with the changes, dont forget to save

```
if(![self.managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error]){
```

Comment: How do I know what the name of the `.sqlite` file is?

Comment: you are creating it here in this line - NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyStore.sqlite"];

Comment: yah you are using addInMemoryPersistentStore .. thats the issue..  MUndi's comment is also valid.. make sure you have valid data you are saving .. before expecting it to come back

Answer (score 0):

You never create a user anywhere in the code you posted. You first fetch all users - and none come back. Then you fetch them again - why do you expect that there is one now? Did you check if the user is `nil` the second time as well?

What you need to to is to insert a new User object if there is none:

```
User *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" 
             inManagedObjectContext:context];

// configure the user
[context save:nil];
```

Comment: There is a user inserted by restkit elsewhere via a call to `getObjectsAtPath:`

Comment: Then, if you checked that the second time around `user` is not `nil` and you call `[context save:nil]` (and `context` is not `nil`), it must be persisted.